# EF core 2.0 reverse engineer my model now can't query DbSets

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.0

I'm new to EF core 2.0 I reversed engineered my database and now have a dbContext file and all my model classes. I'm trying to use linq to query EF but can't get to the Where clause? Can someone point to what I'm doing wrong? Is there a namespace other then System.Linq that I should be using?

This is what I'm trying to do.

var foundObjects = _contextMarketing.T_CustomerCampaigns.Where(o => o.CheckNum.Equals(prospect.offerCode)).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate the files you should have no problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

If you did do that what you should have is a bunch of model classes like:

```
public partial class SomeTable
{ 
    public int SomeValue {get;set;}
}
```

And then a `Context` class similar to this:

```
public partial class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<SomeTable> SomeTable { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

And then your call should be `someContext.SomeTable.Where(...)`.

I presume you have not done the scaffold call and instead done something manually and not created `DbSet<...>` properties in your `DbContext`

Comment: I did use scaffold and I get no Where option when I do what you stated to do. I get Add, Update, Remove, and other things.

Comment: Press F12 on the object you are trying to do Where on.. what line of code and type does it take you to

Comment: It takes me to public virtual DbSet<TCustomerCampaigns> TCustomerCampaigns { get; set; } which is the object.

Comment: Ok so Where should be there no problem. You have in the code file you are typing .Where, the using System.Linq; right? Also if you type TCustomerCampaigns.Where and then hold Ctrl and press . (so the period key) it should bring up a context menu and would prompt to include the namespace if not already